# Keep integer value when re looping

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am having a problem within my for loop. I am currently using node js with ibm db2.

```
var code = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity_Code" FROM TRADES WHERE "Commodity" LIKE \'%\' || ? || \'%\' AND "Aggregate_Level"=4', [productLevelFour]);
        
var commodity_code;
var data;
var resString = "";
for(let i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    commodity_code = code[i]['Commodity_Code'];
    data = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity_Code", "Commodity" FROM TRADES WHERE "Commodity_Code" LIKE \'\' || ? || \'__\' ', [commodity_code]);
            
     for(let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
         resString += j+1 + "." + " " + data[j]['Commodity'] + "\n";
     }
 }
```

In the code above, i want to keep the j value when re-looping in the first for loop. For example, if code.length = 2, the loops will start and var data will be saved in the resString with j at 1. The loop will then restart to complete the next loop but j restarts at 1. I want the value of j to continue from the previous iteration.

Any of you have an idea to fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line resets `j` to zero every time it is encountered

```
for(let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
```

If you want to avoid resetting `j`, change it to

```
for(; j < data.length; j++) {
```

You will want to initialise `j` at the start.

So your code becomes

```
var code = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity_Code" FROM TRADES WHERE "Commodity" LIKE \'%\' || ? || \'%\' AND "Aggregate_Level"=4', [productLevelFour]);
        
var commodity_code;
var data;
var resString = "";
var j = 0; // <=== j is set here
for(let i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
    commodity_code = code[i]['Commodity_Code'];
    data = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity_Code", "Commodity" FROM TRADES WHERE "Commodity_Code" LIKE \'\' || ? || \'__\' ', [commodity_code]);
            
     for(; j < data.length; j++) { // <=== j isn't reset here
         resString += j+1 + "." + " " + data[j]['Commodity'] + "\n";
     }
 }
```

Comment: "every time" is ambiguous here.  If you read this answer on its own without reading the question it seems to say something that is wrong.  (j is not reset to 0 "every time" the loop iterates, for example) You're missing the original context in your explanation, which is that this is a nested loop.  This could be misleading to some, as written.

Comment: I've changed it to say 'every time it is encountered'. Is that unambiguous?

Comment: The code illustrates very well what the solution is.  That much is fine.  The verbal explanation is ambiguous.  Even the part about initializing `j` "at the start" is ambiguous.  Start of what?  The text of the answer doesn't express things as clearly as the code does.  In fact, it almost seems to suggest something that is incorrect (without context of it being a nested loop).  For example "at the start of the outer loop" would be less ambiguous.  And I would omit "every time it is encountered" entirely.  "This line sets j to zero" is fine.  There's no "resetting" of `j`. it's a new var.

Comment: I don't see how this could give the desired result. Now some data will be skipped over, and not included in the result. In the extreme case, when the data for a certain commodity code match has fewer items than the previous matching commodity code, the result will have nothing for that commodity code. I very much doubt that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @trincot I'm a bit baffled by what the 'desired result' is to be honest. I tried to just answer the question as posed. It's quite possible that your answer, which attempts to discern what the code is really supposed to do, is better. However, I can't be sure.

Comment: @Wyck I'm sorry for being ambiguous. I sort of see what you mean, but I don't think it's worth going back over now. If you want to know what 'at the start' means, you have to look at the code, where there's a comment showing where it's set.

Answer (score 2):

Every time the line `for(let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {` is executed, a new variable named `j` with the initial value of `0` is created.

If you want to re-use the same variable, you need to define it outside the context of the loop, so that you don't create a new variable named `j` each time the inner loop is executed.

```js
let j = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log('outer loop');
    for (; j < 10; j++) {
        console.log('inner loop');
    }
    console.log(`i is ${i}, j is ${j}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I assume you only want the numbering to be continuous, but still want all of your data to be included in the result, I don't think it is enough to just let `j` increment without resetting to 0. If you do that, and the outer loop has more than one iteration, you will not have all data in the output.

You could build your result first as an array, and leave the string formatting for the end:

```
var code = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity_Code" FROM TRADES WHERE "Commodity" LIKE \'%\' || ? || \'%\' AND "Aggregate_Level"=4', [productLevelFour]);
        
var result = []; // <--- array
for(let {Commodity_Code} of  code) { // Not required, but nice way of looping
    let data = conn.querySync('SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity_Code", "Commodity" FROM TRADES WHERE "Commodity_Code" LIKE \'\' || ? || \'__\' ', [Commodity_Code]);
    // just push the commodity field to that array for later processing
    result.push(...data.map(({Commotity}) => Commodity)); 
}

// Now format the results
var resString = result.map((commodity, j) => j+1 + ". " + commodity).join("\n");
```